# NDB query giving different results on local versus production environment

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I am banging my head into a wall over this and hoping you can tell me the very simple thing I have overlooked in my sleep deprived/noob state.

Very simply I am doing a query and the type of object returned is different on my local machine than what gets returned once I deploy the application.

```
match = MatchRealTimeStatsModel.queryMatch(ancestor_key)[0]
```

On my local machine the above produces a MatchRealTimeStatsModel object. So I can run the following to lines without a problem:

```
logging.info(match)       # outputs a MatchRealTimeStatsModel object
logging.info(match.match) # outputs a dictionary from json data
```

When the above two lines are run on Goggles machines I get the following though:

```
logging.info(match)       # outputs a dictionary from json data
logging.info(match.match) # AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'match'
```

Any suggestions as to what might be causing this? I cleared the data store and did everything I could think of to clean the GAE environment.

Edit #1: Adding MatchRealTimeStatsModel code:

```
class MatchRealTimeStatsModel(ndb.Model):
    match = ndb.JsonProperty()

    @classmethod
    def queryMatch(cls, ancestor_key):
        return cls.query(ancestor=ancestor_key).fetch()
```

And here is the actual call:

```
ancestor_key = ndb.Key('MatchRealTimeStatsModel', matchUniqueUrl)
match = MatchRealTimeStatsModel.queryMatch(ancestor_key)[0]
```

Comment: If this is a dict then match['match'] should work.

Comment: Yes but then it won't work on my local machine for testing. I would really rather avoid having an if/else statement just for this.

Comment: It is difficult to tell anything without seeing how `MatchRealTimeStatsModel.queryMatch` is implemented.

Comment: Hey Tim, I have added that information in Edit #1 of the OP. Thanks for taking a look. :)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are using different versions of your code locally than in prod?  Try to reset your copy of the source code in both places.